# haproxy backend rewrite

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, haproxy

I would like to achive this with HAProxy:

site.com/web frontend to someserver:8002 in backend with rewrite.

/web in frontend go to / in the backend server and all recursive context

```
frontend /web --> backend /
frontend /web/about-us/ --> /about-us 
frontend /web/img --> backend /img
frontend /web/css --> backend /css
```

This is my config in frontend:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http

    acl is_myweb path_beg /web
    use_backend myweb if is_myweb
```

... and the backend:

```
backend myweb
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /web/(.*) \1\ /\2
    server s2 192.168.192.140:8002
```

It seems works but only in the / context.

For example, if in the frontend have a link to /about-us the requested url is site.com/about-us and this it not rewrited, css is not applied because it's under /css... I think that is necessary to rewrite the frontend to do it but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem, but in your regex, you are not replacing 'frontend' with 'backend' as you wanted. Also can you flip the order like use the root folder at the bottom of listing. I would suggest "frontend /web/css ' and then 'frontend /web/img' ..so on at the end use the root 'frontend /web' .

Comment: HAProxy does not rewrite response bodies to accommodate changing paths.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry... Another example, haproxy hit in the /blog1 context but I like to route it to a backend that the content is another root folder for example /blog2
site.com/blog1
In haproxy create an acl
acl url_blog1 path_beg /blog1
    use_backend blog url_blog1
backend
reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /blog1/(.*) \1\ /blog2\2
    server s2 192.168.192.140:8002

Comment: I think this is the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906648/haproxy-backend-redirect-based-on-path